# Why is the confusion matrix and test error the same despite the LDA being done different datasets

Tags: r, classification, confusion-matrix, linear-discriminant

```
library(ISLR2)
df = Auto
df$mclass <- as.factor(ifelse(df$mpg <20, 'low', ifelse(df$mpg >= 20  & df$mpg < 27, 'medium', 'high')))
```

I have split the dataset into test and training

```
test = df[df$year == 75,]
test.direction = test$mclass
training =  df[df$year !=  75,]
training.direction = training$mclass
```

I have done LDA on entire dataset

```
lda1 = lda(mclass ~ acceleration + displacement + horsepower +  weight, df)
```

ive used only the test dataset to test prediction

```
table (predict(lda1,test)$class, test.direction)
```

Ive then redone LDA using just the training data set (everything not in test data set)

```
lda2 = lda(mclass ~ acceleration + displacement + horsepower +  weight, data = training)
```

and redone the prediction on test data

```
table (predict(lda2,test)$class,test.direction)
```

The results of both predictions are the same - even though the LDA have been done different datasets - I would expect that they would be different?

Comment: the second lda is similar to the first because no subsetting was done. You should have `subset = !test` and not `subset != test`  That is if `test` is a logical vector

Comment: apologies there was a typo in my post - it was as correct as per your msg

Comment: Without a reproducible example, all we can do is throw out random guesses.

Comment: Note that `subset != test` and `subset = !test` are two different things. what is `test`? if `sum(df$test)` is 0 then the two lda will be exactly the same

Comment: @Axeman ive updated the post to hopefully allow reproduction .

Comment: The predictions are similar, but different, see e.g. `plot(predict(lda1,test)$posterior[, 1], predict(lda2,test)$posterior[, 1])`. The models are similar since they have almost the same data. They are so similar that when you just take the most likely predicted class, they give the same answers. This won't be always be the case, but it is somewhat likely to happen in small datasets.